# Git and Active directory configuration

Tags: git

My ActiveDirectory (AD) exists on windows OS and my git test repository on Centos.  I want to integrate GIT and AD so that git operations like clone and push prompts for the AD user/password.  I am able to clone however, it does not prompt me for the login/password.  I have gone thro the answers for similar questions in this forum, but the issue still exists.  Please help.